# how is opportunity line item and schedule are related

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, opp-lineitemschedule

Can any one let me know .How is opportunity line item(Opportunity Product) and Schedule are related .Because i could not the Schedule list in the developer edition when created a opportunity line item ,whereas in my EE i could see.What is the navigation to get the Schedule.Is it a Schedule or an opportunityLineItemSchedule.Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Opportunity Line Item Schedules are only visible after you activated the feature at the Org in question:

```
Setup > Customize > Products > Schedule Setup
```

Once activated, there is a new Standard Object called *OpportunityLineItemSchedule* with a lookup reference to the OpportunityLineItem by the field *OpportunityLineItemId*. This object can be manipulated in APEX with the usual DML operations.